# JavaFX - How to disable/turn off WebViews HTML Renderer

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-8

As in the title: Is it possible to deactivate/turn off the JavaFx WebViews HTML Rendering Engine?
I would like to see the raw HTML-Code in the same WebView-Component.

Changing the `contentType` to `text`, results in an empty WebView:

```
String content = "<HTML><b>test</b></HTML>";
String contentType = "text"; // text/html
webEngine.loadContent(content, contentType);
```

Comment: The mime type for plain text is `text/plain`: try it with `String contentType = "text/plain";`

Comment: You are right! What a fail....when you create an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mime type for plain text is `text/plain`, so you need:

```
String contentType = "text/plain";
```